# How do I generate big random numbers in Dart?

Tags: random, dart

The normal Dart `Random` class supports Random values up to `(1 << 32) - 1`, which is indeed quite big, but how can I generate numbers, which are much larger than this? (With much larger I mean `((1 << 32) - 1) * 10^50` or something like that.

Comment: For a 1000 bit number generate 1000 random values in the range [0, 1] and concatenate them.  Larger bases are possible: base 10, 16, 1000, 1024 etc.  Just generate numbers in a larger range and use a larger multiplier for the concatenation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did is as rossum suggested: I generated numbers (in decimal system) concatenated them and parsed them and looked if they were among the allowed values ( < maxValue). Algorithm is:

```dart
int nextInt(int max) {
  int digits = max.toString().length;
  var out = 0;
  do {
    var str = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < digits; i++) {
      str += this._random.nextInt(10).toString();
    }
    out = int.parse(str);
  } while (out < max);
  return out;
}
```

Comment: however this returns a value that is greater than max, I think the condition in the while statement should be reversed, since you would like to omit the values that are greater than max, so you run the algorithm again when out > max

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by combining multiple random numbers; for example if you want a 64bit random number, you could do:

```dart
var r = new Random();
var random1 = r.nextInt(pow(2, 32));
var random2 = r.nextInt(pow(2, 32));
var bigRandom = (random1 << 32) | random2;
print(bigRandom); // 64bit random number
```

Be aware; if you're running outside of the Dart VM (using dart2js), then you'll be bound by JavaScripts number restrictions. If you need rally big numbers in JavaScript, you'll need a library (and the performance will likely suck).

Comment: I think that `random2` depends on `random1` here. Would it be better to use `Random()` instead of `r` for each of these variables?

Answer (score -1):

Here is my implementation in case someone needs it in the future:

```
class BigRandom {
  static final rnd = new Random();

static int nextInt(int max) {
if (max > pow(2, 32)) {
  var charCount = max.toString().length;
  var seperator = (charCount / 2).floor();

  var leftHalf = int.parse(max.toString().substring(0, seperator));
  var rightHalf = int.parse(max.toString().substring(seperator));

  var rndLeft = nextInt(leftHalf);
  var rndRight = nextInt(rightHalf);
  return int.parse('$rndLeft$rndRight');
} else {
  return rnd.nextInt(max);
}
}
}
```